# Bottle python program runs in dev environment but not in live environment

Tags: python, centos, bottle

I am trying to get [python bottle application](https://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/index.html) running, but for some reason it fails. I am using bottle 0.13 and python 2.7 on cent os 7.2 version.

The same program runs in dev environment which has centos 6.7 but not in live environment. I get the following stack trace:

```
File "helloworld.py", line 7, in <module>run(host='localhost', port=8080)
File "/bottle.py", line 3127, in run server.run(app) File "/bottle.py", line 2781, in run
srv = make_server(self.host, self.port, app, server_cls, handler_cls)
File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/wsgiref/simple_server.py", line 144, in make_server
server = server_class((host, port), handler_class)
File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 420, in _init_self.server_activate()
File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 439, in server_activate
self.socket.listen(self.request_queue_size)
File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/socket.py", line 224, in meth
return getattr(self._sock,name)(*args)socket.error: [Errno 98] Address already in use
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: There is something bound to port 8080 already.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there is already a process listening on port `8080`. You can use the follow command to check who is using `8080`:

```
lsof -i :8080
```

To change the port, edit `port=8080` parameter to some other port and rerun application:

```
run(host='localhost', port=8080)
```